# Requesting OAuth token does not work using code but works using Postman

Tags: c#, oauth, token, visual-studio-2019, webapi

I have tried to make my web API to generate a OAuth web API token using this [Article](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1216/oauth-web-api-token-based-authentication-with-custom-database).It worked fine testing it on postman [image]

but when I try to execute using the code that postman provides for the request I get `response.Content=""` and
`response.StatusCode=0`

```
     var client = new RestClient("https://ip_address/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("username", "Morad.A");
            request.AddParameter("password", "123456");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

What I have tried is adding

```
    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            }
```

to my `Application_Start()` in my web API

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the authorization type usually, OAuth requires Authoriaztion so you have to add auth value to request header.
i.e if auth typs is Basic just add the following:

```
Authorization: Base64(client:secret)
```